# Is possible rename and move forests from old volume to different volume

Tags: marklogic

I have forests live on the server old volume SAN1 directory /ML9/data. But want to move forests to a new volume SAN2 directory /FSA/temp.  But not sure of any impact to rename directory and forests name from new volume /FSA/temp to original name /ML9/data.

For example:

1. Created forest on new volume SAN2 tempForest01 point to directory /FSA/temp
2. Unattached & Retired forest in old volume SAN1 in /ML9/data and attached forest tempForest01 on the new volume.
3. Shutdown database, unmount the old volume SAN1.
4. Rename the directory /FSA/temp/ back to /ML9/data/ and forest tempForest01 to Forest01 from volume SAN2.

step1 and step 2 are done, but not sure about step3 and 4 or any missing additional steps.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You added the new `tempForest01` forest on the new SAN2 and retired the original forest, allowing all of the documents to drain out and rebalance into the new forest, and then detached the old forest, and now are planning to rename the new `tempForest01` forest on SAN2 to have the original `Forest01` name on this new mount?

The overall process described sound correct. I would add explicit checks to verify counts to ensure that all docs have drained out of the original forest and are in the new forest. Maybe take a backup before/after, just in case there are issues.

Keep in mind that the rename is not instant. If you execute a method such as [`admin:forest-rename`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:forest-rename) and then save the configuration with [`admin:save-configuration`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:save-configuration) it will return quickly, but has not yet renamed the forests. It will then perform work asynchronously. Watch the logs to ensure that there are no errors or issues and wait a bit to confirm database status after initiating the rename.

An alternative strategy for getting back to the original forest names would be to perform similar steps to retire and rebalance. Create new forests with the original names, and then retire `tempForest01` and allow it to rebalance docs into `Forest01`, and then detach and delete `tempForest01`.